# What is the correct approach to use if in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I didn't find an answer that satisfies me about this newbie javascript (using jQuery) question...

I have these 2 codes inside a document ready...

**CODE 1**

```
$('myElement').click(function(){
     if(isMobile()){
         //do something...
     }
});
```

**CODE 2**

```
if(isMobile()){
    $('myElement').click(function(){
       // do somthing...
    });
}
```

What is the correct approach and why?

Thanks guys

Comment: The correct approach to what? Your examples do different things. Please be more clear. Code 1 will check your condition every time myElement is clicked, where code 2 will check your condition exactly once, and then bind an click handler if it's true.

Comment: depends what else is happening. If you need the event only if its mobile go with the second but I would most commonly use the first as it gives more freedom and is more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates the click event in any case, and inside of it you do different stuff depending on the condition.

The second option only generates the click event if the condition is true.

So, it depends on the logic of your application. If the click event is only needed if `isMobile()`is true, I'll go with the second option, so you don't generate an event that you aren't going to need.

If you always need the click event, but it has to do different things depending of the `isMobile()` condition, then the first one is the way to go.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

### Code 1

```
$('myElement').click(function() {
  if(isMobile()) {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

The action is always attached to your element.
For each click on your element, it will test if you are on mobile.

### Code 2

```
if(isMobile()) {
  $('myElement').click(function() {
    // do something...
  });
}
```

It will test if you are on mobile first. If so, it will attach your action to your element. If not, you will never get the action when you click on your element.

Here an example :

```js
const isMobile = false

if (isMobile) {
  console.log("code 1 - isMobile")
  $("#code1").click(function() {
    console.log("code 1 - click")
  })
}


  
$("#code1").click(function() {
  console.log("code 2 - click")
  if (isMobile) {
    console.log("code 2 - isMobile")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Code 1</h2>

<button id="code1">Click me !</button>

<h2>Code 2</h2>

<button id="code2">Click me !</button>
```